# Bounding difference of characteristic functions with mixing coefficients

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limit-theorems, mixing

### Setting

Let $X = \{ X(t), t \in \mathbb{R} \}$ be a stationary, $\alpha$-mixing stochastic process and define
$$
\begin{align}
I_{n, l} &= \{ (l - 1)b_{n} + 1 + r_{n}, \ldots, lb_{n} \}, \quad l = 1, \ldots, k_n, \\ 
S_n(I_{n,l}) &= \sum_{j \in I_{n,l}} X(j).
\end{align}
$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and integer sequences $b_n, r_n$ and $k_n = n / b_n$.
Further, let $\tilde{S}_n(I_{n,l})$, $l = 1, \ldots, k_n$, be iid copies of $S_n(I_{n,1})$.

In [1, Eq. 6.2], the authors use *"the definiton of $\alpha$-mixing and standard results for strong mixing sequences (see Doukhan [14])"* to show that for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$

$$
\begin{align}
&\bigg\vert
  \mathbb{E} \prod_{l = 1}^{k_n} e^{itS_n(I_{n, l})}
  -
  \prod_{l = 1}^{k_n} e^{it\tilde{S}_n(I_{n, l})}
\bigg\vert \\
&=
\bigg\vert
\sum_{l = 1}^{k_n} 
  \mathbb{E} \prod_{s = 1}^{l - 1} e^{itS_n(I_{n, s})}
     \big(
        e^{itS_n(I_{n, l})} - e^{it\tilde{S}_n(I_{n, l})}
     \big)
     \prod_{s = l + 1}^{k_n}  e^{it\tilde{S}_n(I_{n, s})}
\bigg\vert  \\
&\leq
\sum_{l = 1}^{k_n} 
\bigg\vert
  \mathbb{E} \prod_{s = 1}^{l - 1} e^{itS_n(I_{n, s})}
     \big(
        e^{itS_n(I_{n, l})} - e^{it\tilde{S}_n(I_{n, l})}
     \big)
     \prod_{s = l + 1}^{k_n}  e^{it\tilde{S}_n(I_{n, s})}
\bigg\vert \\
&\leq 4k_n\alpha_{r_n}
\end{align}
$$

### Questions

1. I'm sure that these are standard techniques with the large blocks/small blocks technique. But I find it hard to follow these steps without knowing the "standard results in [14]" and I couldn't find related inequalities in [14]. Can anyone be more specific as to what standard results are meant here?
2. In the end, I'd like to replace the mixing-coefficient $\alpha_r$ with covariances of the form $\text{Cov}(S_n(I_{n, i}), S_n(I_{n, j}))$, $i, j = 1, \ldots, n$. Are there results of that form available in the literature?

### Literature

[1]  Richard A. Davis. Thomas Mikosch. "The extremogram: A correlogram for extreme events." Bernoulli 15 (4) 977 - 1009, November 2009. https://doi.org/10.3150/09-BEJ213

[14] Doukhan, P. (1994). Mixing. Properties and Examples. Lecture Notes in Statistics 85. New York: Springer-Verlag.

Comment: for both questions, I would take a look at the I.Rio book "Asymptotic Theory of Weakly Dependent Random Processes" https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-54323-8 if you haven't already. There he had variations of the mixing bounds involving moments and covariances of sums.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that book :)